# SQLAlchemy: Combine contains_eager with defer

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There are these SQLAlchemy mapped classes:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sqla.Column(sqla.String)
    assoc_owned_things = relationship('Owns')

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sqla.Column(sqla.String)
    assoc_owned_by = relationship('Owns')

class Owns(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'owns'
    person_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key = True, autoincrement = False)
    person = relationship("Person")
    thing_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('thing.id'), primary_key = True, autoincrement = False)
    thing = relationship("Thing")
    ownership_payload = sqla.Column(sqla.Text)
```

Then this code:

```
person = (session.query(Person).join(Owns).join(Thing).filter(Person.id == id_p2)
    .options(Load(Owns).defer('ownership_payload'), contains_eager(Person.assoc_owned_things, Owns.thing)).one())
print(p2.assoc_owned_things[0].ownership_payload)
```

loads all fields in one query. How make the `ownership_payload` field to be deferred in this query so that accessing it will query the database again? Used `defer` option does not seem to have any impact on ORM behaviour.

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368018/sqlalchemy-undefer-column-via-joinedload-technique