# SQLAlchemy: undefer column via joinedload technique

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is my query.

```
query = dbsession.query(Parent)\
    .options(joinedload(Parent.child))\
    .first()
```

Model `Child` is available through `Parent.child` relationship and has deffered column named 'column'. How to undefer and load that column using query listed above?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.options(undefer(Child.column))` (just guessing)?

Comment: undefer function doesn't accept mappers. See documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.undefer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain the undefer option through the joined load with

```
joinedload(Parent.child).undefer('column')
```

See ["Loading Along Paths"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#loading-along-paths) and the documentation on [loaders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.strategy_options.Load).

Given the following models:

```
In [3]: class A(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'a'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     

In [4]: class B(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'b'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'), primary_key=True)
   ...:     value = deferred(Column(Integer))
   ...:     a = relationship('A', backref='bs')
   ...:
```

undeferring `value`

```
In [21]: print(session.query(A).options(joinedload(A.bs).undefer('value')))
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b_1.value AS b_1_value, b_1.id AS b_1_id 
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b AS b_1 ON a.id = b_1.id
```

without

```
In [17]: print(session.query(A).options(joinedload(A.bs)))
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b_1.id AS b_1_id 
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b AS b_1 ON a.id = b_1.id
```